.txt file being created, but file is blank without invert_dictionary contents (python)
Task: Write a program to read dictionary items from a file and then write the inverted dictionary to a file.
Problem: The new output_file is created, but it's created blank. I've read a few forums and tried to make some changes (like adding a .close(), but this seems to have mixed reviews when already using with), so I've taken that bit out. Unsure where to go next to improve my code and get the right result! New to coding.

tried adding .close() to the code, then removed
tried modifying the contents of input_file, adding curly brackets, making list items strings, etc. -- unsure what is correct here, does it have to be a properly formatted list?
added if line.count section with continue

Current contents of maindictionary.txt
{
   'Art': ['Pocahontas', 'Jasmine', 'Tiana'],
   'Computer Science': ['Rapunzel', 'Cinderella', 'Jasmine', 'Moana'],
   'English': ['Aurora', 'Rapunzel', 'Mulan', 'Tiana', 'Pocahontas'],
   'Geography': ['Belle', 'Cinderella', 'Ariel', 'Thumbelina'],
   'History': ['Cinderella', 'Ariel', 'Thumbelina', 'Aurora'],
   'Physical Education': ['Aurora', 'Mulan', 'Belle', 'Ariel'],
   'Mathematics': ['Jasmine', 'Aurora', 'Rapunzel', 'Moana'],
   'Science': ['Moana', 'Tiana', 'Pocahontas', 'Thumbelina', 'Belle']
}

Current code
    # indicate the file paths for the two files
    input_file = "/Python/maindictionary.txt"
    output_file = "/Python/inverteddictionary.txt"

    # read the original dictionary from a file
    def read_dictionary(input_file):
        main_dictionary = {}
        with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                if line.count(',') != 1:
                    continue
                key, value = line.strip().split(',')
                main_dictionary[key.strip()] = value.strip()
        return main_dictionary

    # invert the dictionary
    def invert_dictionary(main_dictionary):
        inverted_dictionary = {}
        for key, value in main_dictionary.items():
            if value not in inverted_dictionary:
                inverted_dictionary[value] = [key]
            else:
                inverted_dictionary[value].append(key)
        return inverted_dictionary

    # write the inverted dictionary to a different file
    def write_inverted_dictionary(inverted_dictionary, output_file):
        with open(output_file, 'a') as file:
            for key, value in inverted_dictionary.items():
                file.write(f"{key}: {', '.join(value)}\n")

    # read the main dictionary from the file
    main_dictionary = read_dictionary(input_file)

    # invert the main dictionary, like in programming assignment 7
    inverted_dictionary = invert_dictionary(main_dictionary)

    # write the inverted dictionary to a new file
    write_inverted_dictionary(inverted_dictionary, output_file)


Every single line in the maindictionary.txt file has either no commas or more than one comma, so the condition line.count(',') != 1: is always true, so it ends up skipping all the lines in the file, so main_dictionary is empty.

Ah, that was my attempt to correct a different ValueError -- I'll go back down that path though next, thanks @John Gordon.

Your input file appears to contain a string representation of a Python dictionary. Note: It is not JSON
The ast module offers a simple mechanism for decoding such a file.
You can the use the json module to help with formatting the output file.
from ast import literal_eval
import json
from pathlib import Path

INPUT_FILE = Path("maindictionary.txt")
OUTPUT_FILE = Path("inverteddictionary.txt")

with INPUT_FILE.open() as fd:
    maindictionary: dict[str, list[str]] = literal_eval(fd.read())

    inverted_dictionary: dict[str, list[str]] = {}

    for k, v in maindictionary.items():
        for _v in v:
            inverted_dictionary.setdefault(_v, []).append(k)
    
    with OUTPUT_FILE.open("w") as output:
        output.write(json.dumps(inverted_dictionary, indent=2))

